# How to set QTcpSocket heartbeat interval?

Tags: python, pyqt

I notice Qt `QTcpSocket setSocketOption(QTcpSocket.KeepAliveOption, 1)` can keep two connection alive, but I don't know how to set `KeepAlive` interval?  ç

In python can simply do by this `sock.ioctl(socket.SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS, (1, 10000, 3000))`, So is there has a simple way in Qt like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the QTcpSocket file descriptor to create a python socket object to be able to use the required method:

```py
import socket
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QAbstractSocket, QTcpSocket


def main():
    app = QCoreApplication([])

    qtcpsocket = QTcpSocket()

    def handle_connected():
        print("CONNECTED")
        if (
            sys.platform == "win32"
            and qtcpsocket.state() != QAbstractSocket.SocketState.UnconnectedState
        ):
            fd = int(qtcpsocket.socketDescriptor())
            print(fd)
            pysocket = socket.socket(fileno=fd)
            pysocket.ioctl(socket.SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS, (1, 10000, 3000))

        QCoreApplication.quit()

    qtcpsocket.connected.connect(handle_connected)
    qtcpsocket.connectToHost("google.com", 80)

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note: The file descriptor returned by method [`QTcpSocket::socketDescriptor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#socketDescriptor) is valid while the connection is active.